# Beautiful Soup_ extraction within class

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract element in BeautifulSoup object.

By specifying div class, I got the following containers and I am inspecting one of them - first_water.

```
water_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'display-inline-block pull-left prod-ProductCard--Image')
first_water = water_containers[0]
```

Further in to get a class in it gave the following:

```
test = first_water.a
```

a class="" href="/ip/Nestle-Pure-Life-Purified-Water-8-Fl-Oz-24-Count/47757005" itemprop="url"> img alt="Nestle Pure Life Purified Water, 8 Fl Oz, 24 Count" class="Tile-img" height="180" src="//i5.walmartimages.com/asr/d8c48736-7833-48bb-83a5-577bfc56a8b5_1.f60d9d33c9a8030ace5fd7e653190c98.jpeg?odnWidth=180&odnHeight=180&odnBg=ffffff" width="180"/>/a

I would like to extract the information in href= "..." The /ip/Nestle-Pure-Life-Purified-Water....

I tried partition:

```
test.partition('href=')
test.split('href=', 1)
```

But it gives error saying 'NoneType' object is not callable.

I think there should be simpler way to extract the object in href.. but I am not quite sure what to do. a tag is the lowest level I could get.

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far and a full error traceback.. Your question is currently very vague..

Comment: Please post your tried effort and url

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding details. Could you have a look? (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
link = first_water.a['href']
```

Comment: Wow. It works! Thank you so~~~ much for your help, drec4s (: Have a lovely day.